# How to create a series of dates in Cocoa for a week

Tags: cocoa, date

I am current writing an application and need to show the current days of the week.

So, for the coming week I need to generate the follow dates.

Monday, 5 January 2009
Tuesday, 6 January 2009
Wednesday, 7 January 2009
Thursday, 8 January 2009
Friday, 9 January 2009

I have already coded the application to generate five dates from the current date. The problem I have is finding a method to create Monday through to Friday on the current week.

I am running OS X 10.5 and am using the Cocoa environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) and [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you haven't, you should read [Dates and Times Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) for more info/help.